# Android auto randomly disconnecting and reconnecting, likely when phone is 100% charged

Tags: android-auto

When I plug in my phone to the car in the morning (USB connection) it is likely to disconnect and reconnect 3-5 times before settling out.  It also does this in the summer when the phone and car are hot.  I came across this issue report about the USB being disabled when the phone is at 100% charge (and, my speculation, when charging is disabled due to temperature):

https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/15209528

This thread is 2+ years old though. Is there a fix or workaround?  Admittedly, my phone is a few years old, but still.

Comment: Please provide some details of your phone, which may help the community to provide an answer?

Comment: It's a Pixel 3, not rooted or anything.